# How to configure SublimeLinter 4.0.1

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm using Sublime Text 3, and SublimeLinter just upgraded itself to version 4.0.1.

I've read the docs but can't work out how to get it working properly. I have tried copying the default settings into user settings and changing them but it has made no difference (this is via Preferences > Package Settings > Sublime Linter > Settings).

The gutter icons are all just white; I've tried setting it to:

```
"gutter_theme": "Default",
```

I've also tried changing the icon in styles:

```
"styles": [
        {
            "mark_style": "outline",
            "priority": 1,
            "scope": "region.yellowish markup.changed.sublime_linter markup.warning.sublime_linter",
            "icon": "warning",
            "types": [
                "warning"
            ]
        },
        {
            "mark_style": "outline",
            "priority": 1,
            "scope": "region.redish markup.deleted.sublime_linter markup.error.sublime_linter",
            "icon": "error",
            "types": [
                "error"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

The outline around error text is now incredibly faint and I can barely see it; previously it was clear and bright.

Anybody know how to configure the new version to highlight errors clearly and show different icons for warnings, errors? Thanks for any help!

(How I wish this hadn't updated itself. The docs say you can manually install an older version but that looks like another project in itself, I just want to get on with some work!)

Edit: more fiddling around and setting `"mark_style": "fill",` in "styles" has at least made the errors visible on the page. But I can't figure out how to get the gutter icons to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not you, there's an open issue on GitHub. [See here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/1051).